# How to properly load images on custom UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm at this all afternoon and I can't figure it, so your help would be awesome! I have a custom UICollectionViewCell which I'm populating with images I create on the fly. The paths of the images are stored in Parse and after the query is done, I call `[self.collectionView reloadData].`

In my cellForItemAtIndexPath I have the following code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

MovieCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
// Configure the cell
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"original_title" ascending:YES];
[self.moviesforWatchlist sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort, nil]];
cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[cell addSubview:spinner];

NSDictionary *movie = self.moviesforWatchlist[indexPath.row];
NSString *moviePosterPath = movie[@"poster_path"];
NSString *posterURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342%@", moviePosterPath];
NSURL *posterImage = [NSURL URLWithString:posterURL];
UIImage *cachedImage = [self.imageCache objectForKey:posterImage];

if (cachedImage) {
    cell.imageView.image = cachedImage;
}
else if (cell.imageView.image == nil) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default_collectionviewcell.jpeg"];
    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("get image data", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        [spinner startAnimating];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:posterImage];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [spinner stopAnimating];
            MovieCollectionViewCell *updateCell = (id)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if (updateCell) {
                updateCell.imageView.image = image;
                [updateCell reloadInputViews];
                [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
         }
        });
        [self.imageCache setObject:image forKey:posterImage];
    });
    }
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
return cell;
}
```

I'm calling the query method like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self getWatchlistData];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

This results in a flashing of images until the images are loaded on to UICollectionViewCells. I want the images displayed in my collectionviewcell to be in alphabetical order, so I'm sorting my array that holds the paths to do so, in `cellforitemsatindexpath` is this whats causing the flashing of images? Or is it something else? Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things I would change:

1. I wouldn't sort your array in `cellForItemsAtIndexPAth`.  That method is called as each cell is displayed on screen, so you are potentially resorting it numerous times when that is not necessary.  If your data is changing between one cell being created and the next, then the re-sorting is likely to mess up the link between the collectionView `indexPath.row` and your array index.  I would sort the array when it is populated, perhaps in your `viewWillAppear` or `getWatchlistData` methods.  If the data does change after this, use some of the other collectionView delegate/datasource methods to handle inserts/deletes/moves.  But I don't think this is causing the flickering of images.
2. In the code which you post back to the main queue, you call the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, update the cell image and call `reloadInputViews` (which presumably reconfigures the cell in some way).  But you then call `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` for all visible cells.  What this will do is cause your collectionView to re-call the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` datasource method for each visible item, causing the image for each to be reloaded from the cache.  I think this is the cause of your flickering.  I would just save the downloaded image to the cache, and then call `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` for just the one indexPath that's affected.  The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` datasource method will be called, and will recover the image from the cache and add it to the new cell.
3. Likewise, I think the `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` at the end of your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is superfluous and is likely to contribute to the flickering.
4. I think you are at risk of some cell reuse problems - for example, you add the spinner to every cell.  But the dequeued cells might have been displayed before and therefore already have a spinner (albeit stopped and so probably hidden).  If you scroll back and forth a lot, you might end up with cells with loads of spinners, wasting memory.  I would give the spinner a tag before adding it as a subView, and then use `viewWithTag` to determine whether a spinner has already been added to the dequeued cells (if so, remove it).  And only add the spinner if necessary (i.e. in your `if ...image == nil` clause).
5. Perhaps unlikely, but if the dequeued cell has a default image (so cell.imageView.image != nil) and is being reused for a cell for which the image has not yet been cached (so cachedImage == nil), then none of your dispatch methods will be executed, so the image will never be downloaded.

Sorry if that's a bit heavy, but I hope it's of use.

Comment: No worries! I really appreciate your feedback. I just started learning Objective-C, iOS Development and programming in general, so these kind of answers are awesome. I learn what I did wrong, but it's still up to me to get it working properly. 
And about that... I think it's working now! I'm sorting the array, when it's populated in the getWatchListData method (this seemed to make a big difference). And basically I did all your suggestions. The only thing is that on first load, sometimes the cells get populated with the wrong image. Any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: Only a couple of pointers: first, check your cache is correctly populated.  It may have been populated incorrectly in a previous run, even though your code may now be fine.  And secondly, look out for cell re-use problems, particularly if you see the same images appearing when you scroll through the list.  I find NSLog and breakpoints are really helpful for tracking down that kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, when any image got download then it flicks the view. I am going before like reload that cell, so it will call some delegate methods of collectionview. So i removed it and make a separate method for reload cell. Now when any new image got reload then i call call this method instead of reloadCellForIndexPath:. In custom method just copy paste code from your cellForItemAtIndexPath:. Assign cell in custom method. 
    CollectionPhotoItem *cell = (CollectionPhotoItem*)[self.collection cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

That's it. it will shows your cell without any flicks. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try to use [DLImageLoader](https://github.com/AndreyLunevich/DLImageLoader-iOS)

```
[[DLImageLoader sharedInstance] displayImageFromUrl:@"image_url_here"
                                      imageView:@"UIImageView here"];

[[DLImageLoader sharedInstance] loadImageFromUrl:@"image_url_here"
                                   completed:^(NSError *error, UIImage *image) {
                                        if (error == nil) {
                                            // if we have no any errors
                                        } else {
                                            // if we got an error when load an image
                                        }
                                   }];
```